# Google auth handler on swift

Tags: ios, swift, oauth

I am working on app with Google OAuth 2.0, using this manual: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in?ver=swift and everything works perfect. On my ViewController:

```
class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController, GIDSignInUIDelegate {...}
```

I have a button, executed:

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
```

for completing authentication. After auth complete successfully,  in AppDelegate.swift file executed method:

```
 public func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {...}
```

Additionally I need after auth complete successfully execute method from MyTableViewController. How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not know is it correct, but I did:

```
class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController, GIDSignInUIDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {...
override func viewDidLoad() {
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
}
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
funcIneed()
}
}
```

And it helps me.